# iOS Sharing our own location to Other?

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps, uibutton, mkmapview

- **sharing our 'location' by Clicking on 'Button'?**
- I want to `share` our **`current location`** from self 'viewcontroller'  to `Next view controller`
- as like **`whatsApp`** and **`FaceBook`** **`location Sharing`**

  **is it Possible to Share Our Own Location?**

Comment: your question is not in clear, which one you used `MKMapview` or `GoogleMap`

Comment: please provide proper information about your question http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik....using Gmaps/mapKit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

.h

```
   CLLocationManager *locationManager;
```

.m

```
locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone;
locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyHundredMeters;
[locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
[locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];

latitude = locationManager.location.coordinate.latitude;
longitude = locationManager.location.coordinate.longitude;
```

send it where u want.